# C++: Hex to Decimal Conversion Function - Not getting correct output

Tags: c++, hex, decimal, converters

I'm trying to convert hex values to decimal. I'm just trying to extract either a number (0-9) or letter (A-F), which I'm converting to the number value with another function, and then push the values into a stack (I could have used vector, but chose stack this time). I'm then just trying to get the decimal value, and since a stack works backwards, it should be in order.

The correct output, as shown below, should be 1728, but I'm getting 12.

Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>
#include <stack>

using namespace std;

int hexCharToDec(char a);
void hexToDecimal(string str, stack<int> & myStack);

int main(){

    stack<int> myStack;
    string str = "6C0"; // should be 1728
    hexToDecimal(str, myStack);

}

void hexToDecimal(string str, stack<int> & myStack){

    int totalVal = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){

        if (str.at(i) <= 9)
        myStack.push(str.at(i));

        else if (str.at(i) >= 'A' && str.at(i) <= 'F')
        myStack.push(hexCharToDec(str.at(i)));
    }

    int k = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < myStack.size(); i++){
      totalVal += (myStack.top() * pow(16, k++));

      myStack.pop();

    }
    cout << totalVal;
}

int hexCharToDec(char hexChar){

  switch(hexChar){

      case 'A':
      return 10;
      break;

      case 'B':
      return 11;
      break;

      case 'C':
      return 12;
      break;

      case 'D':
      return 13;
      break;

      case 'E':
      return 14;
      break;

      case 'F':
      return 15;
      break;
}}
```

Comment: What about simply using the `std::hex` IO-manipulator?

Comment: I have to say, the code is extraordinarily complicated for what it does. I'd look for ways to simplify it (without resorting to built-in functions, as I imagine that would defeat the point of the exercise).

Comment: ...aaand the code is edited to fix the first problems and have new problems

Comment: Um.. elaborating the first comment in this question, [why not just do this?](http://ideone.com/txTxcy), or.. [even this](http://ideone.com/S2dnmE)

Comment: I'm very aware of std::hex - If I could do it that way, I wouldn't be here.

Comment: Thanks everyone I have it fixed. I don't really understand the negative ratings, though. Did I do something against Stack Overflow policy or something? I feel like this was an honest question and problem.

Comment: @user2411290 Your morphing the posted code (twice), making all posted answers and most of the comments utterly irrelevant. that may have something to do with it. dunno for sure. Right now if someone saw the code the only "correct" answer would be "There's nothing wrong with your code."

Comment: Thanks Craig, I posted the original code just now. I didn't even realize what I was doing. I definitely deserved the negative ratings. Anyway, thanks for the help guys. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the original version of the code you posted, you mixed up `0` with `'0'` and likewise for the other digits. The output was `12` because if you take `6C0` and ignore the `6` and `0`, the result is `C` which is `12`.

In the updated version this loop is broken:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myStack.size(); i++)
{
    totalVal += (myStack.top() * pow(16, i));
    myStack.pop();
}
```

When you do `pop()`, it reduces `size()`. So you only actually process half of the digits in the stack (rounded up). To fix this, loop until `myStack.size() == 0` instead.

Comment: need to change `i<myStack.size()` in the for condition to be just `myStack.size()`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the characters you're inputting aren't in the range of your `if` statements. The digit characters don't have the values `0`-`9`, they are `'0'`-`'9'` - a different thing altogether. Those characters don't get processed at all.

In addition, your `for` loop is looping over the size of the stack - but the size of the stack is changing as you pop things off the end. You're only processing half of the input.

Answer (score 0):

A working solution:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
int main()
{
    int n;
    string str = "6C0";
    istringstream sin(str);
    sin>>hex>>n;
    cout<<n<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This can't handle as wide a range as the original code can (e.g. `INT_MAX+1`)